# The second Snackbar below a toolbar

Tags: android, snackbar

I'm conscious that in more cases there should be only 1 snack bar, but in my app, the best UX will be when I will display undo bar on the bottom and in the same time all alerts will be displayed on the top.
Snackbar from support library doesn't work like that. Do you know any library that will let me display alerts on the top and undo bar at the bottom?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like [this library on github .](https://github.com/AndreiD/TSnackBar)

*Do let me know if this was useful.*

Answer (score 1):

this library dose what you want
[TSnackBar (Github)](https://github.com/AndreiD/TSnackBar)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library such as https://github.com/Tapadoo/Alerter for in-app alerts (which appear at the top of the screen) and tie this in with your current snackbar-related code.